# Migration Xero oauth 1.0a to 2.0 (JAVA)

Tags: java, sdk, backend, xero-api

I have an integration with Xero oauth 1.0a (backend side in JAVA), where use the sdk to  created contacts, invoices, credit notes. I need migrate Xero to oauth 2.0, because is current version was depreacted. 
Now, I use the dependencies:

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.xeroapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>xero-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.xeroapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>xeroapi-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

What is the solution to migration to Xero in server side without user interaction?

I looked the posts but not understand a conclusion:

- https://community.xero.com/developer/discussion/109207632
- https://central.xero.com/s/question/0D53m00005oHlkN/oauth2-client-credential-grant-server-side-communication-with-xero?t=1580332061000

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Hi @roliveira = the migration strategy is also outlined here: https://developer.xero.com/documentation/oauth2/migrate

It shows the strategy to exchange your Oauth1 tokens for Oauth2 tokens without requiring any users to re-authenticate.

Comment: Hello. In this article, they explicit what the migration in version 1.0a to 2.0, not the other way round. right?

Comment: I need adapted my code to use oauth 2.0 in backend side. In xero github (https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-Java) is available an frontend implementation where is necessary user interaction to accept and generate keys.

Comment: Sorry @roliveira - not sure I understand the question.